# Heroku restart invalidates existing cookie sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, heroku

Each time I push to Heroku, it appears to invalidate user's cookie sessions, causing them to have to sign in again.

I'm using Rails cookie-based sessions. To my knowledge, the only thing that would "reset" a cookie is if the secret key base that was used to encrypt/sign it was changed or invalidated in some way.

I don't believe that's the case, as I'm using a fixed ENV variable each time

```
# config/secrets.yml
default: &default
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV.fetch("SECRET_KEY_BASE") %>

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

staging:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

Anything else that Heroku does on restart that might invalidate a previous cookie?

Comment: Well I think a server reset is going to wipe the session ids from memory, so wouldn't that reset the sessions?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of cookie storage that all the information resides client side on the user's browser? It should persist across multiple server restarts as long as the server-side key used to sign those cookies (`SECRET_KEY_BASE` here) remains constant

Comment: You're right. This seems weird. The only other thing I can think that would invalidate the cookie is if it had an invalid timestamp, but I don't see how or why a reset on the server would change whatever time the time stamp validator is dependent on.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We are having the same problem it seems..